# Is there any solution to initialize variable in update function of unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It is my first time to make a simple 2D game by Unity and I've got a problem.
I want to fade in and out the text stage by stage.

```
using System.Collections;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using UnityEngine;    
using UnityEngine.UI;    

public class StageSet : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text stage;
    Created c = new Created();           //script of level was made already
    float time = 0;
    float fades = 0;
    float fadex = 1;

    void Update ()
    {
        stage = GetComponent<Text>();
        stage.text = "Stage " + c.getLevel();
        time += Time.deltaTime;

        if (time > 2 && time<=3.0f && c.getLevel()==1)
            Fadein();
        if (time > 3.0f && time < 5 && c.getLevel()==1)
            Fadeout();
    }

    void Fadein()
    {
        if (fades < 1)
        {
            fades += 0.1f;
            stage.color = new Color(255, 0, 0, fades);
        }
    }

    void Fadeout()
    {
        if(fadex > 0)
        {
            fadex -= 0.1f;
            stage.color = new Color(255, 0, 0, fadex);  
        }
    }
}
```

It works as my intention at once but I can't implement the function of Fadein and Fadeout anymore because of update function.Is there any solution of initializing the variable fades and fadex after i use Fadein and Fadeout function?

Comment: "can't use the function Fadein and Fadeout anymore because of update function" Can you elaboate on what that means? I´m not familiar with unity, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It means I can't use Fadein and Fadeout any more

Comment: Why do you think repeating what you´ve stated above helps in any way? What do you mean? Do you get an error? Any unexpected results? What exactly means "can´t use"?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry It means I can't implement Fadein and Fadeout function anymore after i use first because when i run the unity project, update function is called frame by frame so there's a problem about initializing the variable to use Fadein and Fadeout

Comment: " there's a problem about initializing the variable" can you be more precise? I think you can totally use your functions in update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could do something like this:

```
void Fadein()
{
 if (fades < 1)
 {
    fades += 0.1f;
    stage.color = new Color(255, 0, 0, fades);
    fadex = fades;
 }
}

void Fadeout()
{
 if(fadex > 0)
 {
    fadex -= 0.1f;
    stage.color = new Color(255, 0, 0, fadex);  
    fades = fadex
 }
}
```

But of course there are more ways to do this, one way would be by making two fade in and fade out Ienumerator methods and then run them on Co-routines, rather than on Update().

Comment: Thank you for taking care of the problems
and Sorry for my English skill.

Comment: You are welcome @FlowORemi :) and welcome to the community.